# How can I get rid of the LaTeX warning: Float too large for page?

Tags: floats, captions, warnings

In my document, I have figures that have a rather long caption. The code I use to include them looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../fig.pdf}
    \caption[Short caption]{Fairly long text...}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

For some of the figures, I keep getting warnings like this one:

```
LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 2.38557pt on input line 339.
```

I can't see anything wrong with the figures in the output document, but it makes the compilation output harder to read because it is full of such warnings.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get rid of these warnings?

Comment: I was struggling a lot with different solutions including playing with \vspace{-Xmm}. Until I came up with this solution that perfectly works for huge images/tables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44439837/2961878

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The warnings tell you that the float (figure and caption) are too long for staying in a page. You will get rid of many of those warnings if you avoid the `center` environment:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../fig.pdf}
  \caption[Short caption]{Fairly long text...}
\end{figure}
```

(it should be avoided anyway, see [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures)).

For pretty high figures you might also want to shorten their width, say `0.95\textwidth` or less. LaTeX won't apply such a transformation for you: the warning simply tells that a float needs attention, but how to solve the problem depends on factors that only a human can evaluate properly.

Comment: How could one suppress this warning but not change the page layout or the size of the figure?

Comment: @lblb Why would you suppress the warning?

Comment: @egreg: I get this warning myself and I just want to leave the offending figure exactly as it is. It's likely both too wide and too long for the page. To be clear I only want to suppress the one warning for the one figure, not all warnings of this kind.

Comment: @lblb This mostly depend on the actual code and why you don't care about the excess height.

Comment: @egreg: I found a solution for my case: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404301/enlargethispage-command-inside-a-float `\enlargethispage` didn't work for the float page.

Answer (score 11):

If the overfullness is not actually a problem: it worked for me to add `\vspace{-Xpt}` before the `\end{figure}`.

In my case the complaint was about an utterly inconsequential `0.04999pt` and so I did not want to split the figure or do anything else to the input, just get the useless-in-this-case warning to go away.

Comment: Great! I added the same \vspace{-Xpt} before the end of the table and it worked. I had a long table though, and I needed to use top and bottom margins.

Comment: This worked like a a charm!

Comment: FYI, I am using table and landscape, and had to put it before \end{table}

Answer (score 1):

In case one has figures boxed (e.g. with the `floatrow` package) the `\vspace` solution disrupts the boxing (i.e. the box will cut the figure at `\textheight`). The problem can be fixed by extending the text area of the `floatpage`.

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{largefigure}[1][0pt]{ 
  \clearpage % finish last page and flush previous floats
  % save current textheight
  \newlength{\@prevtextheight}\setlength{\@prevtextheight}{\textheight} 
  % extend textheight and recompute internal float parameters
  \setlength{\textheight}{\textheight + #1}
  \global\@colht\textheight % reset \@colht 
  \global\@colroom\textheight % reset \@colroom
  \@floatplacement
  % force float to appear at top of page
  \setlength{\@fptop}{0pt} 
  \begin{figure}[!p]
}{
  \end{figure}
  \clearpage % flush the float
  % restore textheight and all
  \setlength{\textheight}{\@prevtextheight}
  \global\@colht\textheight 
  \global\@colroom\textheight
  \@floatplacement
  \setlength{\@fptop}{0pt plus 1fill}
}
\makeatother
```

The solution to your problem then becomes:

```
\begin{largefigure}[3pt] % extend text area by 3pt
  \cenetring
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../fig.pdf}
  \caption[Short caption]{Fairly long text...}
\end{largefigure}
```

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to actually changing the dimensions of an offending image or float, which is too tall and/or too wide for the text area, I personally often work with carefully scaled graphics that only overshoot the margins by a few millimeters. I would employ these two techniques to silence these warnings gracefully:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

% image too wide
\begin{figure}
    \makebox[\textwidth][c]{% fix, centers image in textblock
        \includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{example-image}
    }
\end{figure}

% image too tall
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[height=1.1\textheight]{example-image-golden-upright}
    \vspace{-60pt} % fix
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of MWE]

The first one handles bad box warnings and places the image inside a `\makebox`, which will here center the image on the text area no matter how wide it is. The second example deals with too high images: `\enlargethispage` doesn't work with float environments (see [\enlargethispage command inside a float](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404301/enlargethispage-command-inside-a-float)), so we need to insert a negive height at the end of the `figure` environment contents to fool LaTeX successfully.